# How to handle a asp.net 3.5 JSON response on client side datatables (jquery)?

Tags: asp.net, json, datatables

I want to load a datatables with AJAX in ASP.Net 3.5 and JSON.

I did this before like perfect in ASP.Net 2.0 and JSON  and it works fine - the main reason here is, that in ASP.net 3.5 there is a underline object 'd' in the json response, which is not in ASP.net 2.0.

So in ASP.Net 2.0 I can simply call my ASP.Net site, get a response of JSON and simply add it native on datatables just like raw JSON (and add a 'data' in fron ob the object).
In ASP.Net I can't simply add a 'Data: [Object]' to my JSON because the inbuild asp.net json parser will parse it like: {"d": {"data" : {DATA HERE} } what is something datatables can't handle!

```
 $('#itemOverviewTable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "bServerSide" : false,
        "ajax": 
            {
                url: "AjaxRequest.aspx/GetAllItems"
            },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "link" },
            { "data": "image" },
            { "data": "group" },
            { "data": "order" },
            { "data": "isVisible" }
        ]
    });
```

and

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string GetAllItemsForUser(string userID)
        {
            DAL.ItemHandler itemHandler = new DAL.ItemHandler();
            string items = itemHandler.GetAllItemsForUser(userID);
            return items;
        }
```

I read though this:
http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/
but this is only usefull when I can control my client side ajax call - which I can't in the datatables lib...

any ideas?

Comment: How does the JSON look like? (a small example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
    $('#itemOverviewTable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "dom": "frtip",
        "sAjaxSource": "AjaxRequest.aspx/GetAllItems",
        "fnServerData": dataTableASP35AJAXConverter,
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "Link" },
            { "data": "Image" },
            { "data": "Group" },
            { "data": "Order" },
            { "data": "IsVisible" }
        ]
    });
}

function dataTableASP35AJAXConverter(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        "dataType": 'json',
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success":
                    function (msg) {
                        var json = jQuery.parseJSON('{"data" : ' + msg.d + '}');
                        fnCallback(json);
                    },
        "error":
            function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
    })
}
```